# Search not working properly on front end website, we are using Magento 1.7.02

Tags: magento-1.7, search

I have a problem with our search on front page of our website.
It is not showing the correct result, 
For ex:  I search blood Bank, it searched lot of thing related and unrelated, but didn't find the product I was expecting. I made sure all the words are existing. I even tried to find the same product by SKU code, but it didn't appear that way as well.
The manage stock is no, so there is not issue with the inventory.
I did find, If I disable and then re-enable that product, it starts searching those products. What is this issue and can it be fixed. Can I disable and re-enable the products in group rather then doing it one by one

Thanks
Raj

Answer (score 1):

Did you rebuild catalog search index at System / Index Management (try rebuil all indexes)

Comment: HI Alex,Thanks for suggestion it worked well

Comment: There is another issue now, it is searching all the words separately, eg; if I want to search red tub, it will find all product with word red and word tube, which is bringing huge data in search.

Comment: Native magento search use OR logic. You need install additional extension for improve relevance of search results (for example Advanced Sphinx Search by Mirasvit).

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 different search methods/options in Magento CE 1.7 - Fulltext, Like & Fulltext & like combined. You can locate the settings at System > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog Search. I would suggest using Combined, but please not that Magento's search is not the greatest.

Can I disable and re-enable the products in group rather then doing it one by one

Yes, you can do that. On the Catalog > Manage Products section, use the Actions drop down on the upper right. You will want to select 'Update Attributes' or 'Change Status' and also select the products you would like to bulk edit.

Also as Alex asked, make sure you run indexes on a regular basis, in this case the Catalog Search Index.